# How can I search the first word of the last line of a file and then find it in another file to delete the next line with that pattern in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

heres the first file say **FILE1.txt** with detials :

```
aardvar 555-5553 1200/300 B
alponet 555-3412 2400/1200/300 A
barflyx 555-7685 1200/300 A
bitesup 555-1675 2400/1200/300 A
camelot 555-0542 300 C
```

then search pattern "camelot" in another File say FILE2.txt and delete just the next line with that pattern.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

```
word=$(tail -n1 FILE1.txt | awk '{print $1;}')
grep -v $word FILE2.txt > FILE2.txt.modified
```

However, this only works if the word only occurs once in `FILE2.txt`.

Comment: Hi Robin Thanks for your answer. can I remove the line next what is stored in "Word"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Here Camelot is last line in  FILE1 so I want to keep it in FILE2 and delete the line just after it.